# nodejs Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In my UserService class I am trying to call my base class constructor with super. If i try to do this I get the following error: `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

Here is my UserService class

```
import { Service } from './Service';

class UserService extends Service {
  constructor(model) {
    //Calls Service contructor with specified model.
    super(model);
  }
}

export default { UserService };
```

And this is the base class:

```
import autoBind from 'auto-bind';

class Service {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
    autoBind(this);
  }
}

export default { Service };
```

I looked around a little bit, and some people say it may have to do with the class names that are not spelled correctly. I checked mine but they are all correct.

Other people say it could be the way how these classes are exported and imported.

I am not very familiar with different export syntax so maybe this could be the problem?

**Update:**

It indeed had to do with the way I imported and exported things.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your issue. It's possible you didn't import the services correctly. Here is a working example:

`Service.js`:

```js
import autoBind from 'auto-bind';

class Service {
  model;
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
    autoBind(this);
  }
}

export { Service };
```

`UserService.js`:

```js
import { Service } from './Service';

class UserService extends Service {
  constructor(model) {
    super(model);
  }
}

export { UserService };
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { UserService } from './UserService';

const model = { name: 'teresa teng' };

const userService = new UserService(model);
console.log(userService.model.name);
```

Output:

```
teresa teng
```